# Cannot convert from String[] to String

Tags: java, android, string

Here is my code.. I want to find just a name of city from latitude and longitude.. 
Now i get this :

```
"Address[addressLines=[0:"Mustamäe tee 145",1:"12918 Tallinn",2:"Estonia"],feature=145,admin=Harju County,sub-admin=null,locality=Tallinn,thoroughfare=Mustamäe tee,postalCode=12918,countryCode=Estonia,countryName=null,hasLatitude=true,latitude=59.4123264,hasLongitude=true,longitude=24.6903851,phone=null,url=null,extras=null]"
```

I tried to convert it to string and split it.. i made a String array but when i try to assign "cityName" to String array "name" I get this error - "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String[] to String"

Can you tell me please where am I wrong?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class GPSHelper {
static double latitude;
static double longitude;
static String[] name = new String[5];

public static void getCity(LocationManager lm, Context appContext) {

    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };

    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener);

    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    Geocoder userLocation = new Geocoder(appContext, Locale.getDefault());   
    List<Address> cityName;
    try {
        cityName = userLocation.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        if(cityName != null && !cityName.isEmpty()) {
            for(int i=0; i<5; i++){

            name[i] = cityName.get(0).toString().split("");

            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the answers here are fine.
But what I wonder is why would you use a split on empty character?

Do you know it returns array of single characters (and nothing at start)?

Checkout the code:

```
String str ="dasd";
String[] strr = str.split("");
for(int i=0; i < strr.length;i++)
    System.out.println("i="+i+";str="+strr[i]);
```

Output:

```
i=0;str=
i=1;str=d
i=2;str=a
i=3;str=s
i=4;str=d
```

I would suggest that since `cityName.get(0)` returns Address object have a method there which will return you its name, like below.

```
name[i] = cityName.get(0).getName();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm so stupid:).. Thanks.... But helped this : name=cityName.get(0).getLocality();

Comment: @Sergio pleasure to help. Enjoy Java

Answer (score 2):

```
name[i] = cityName.get(0).toString().split("");
```

`name[i]` is of type `String` while  `cityName.get(0).toString().split("")` is of type `String[]`

Answer (score 1):

```
name[i] = cityName.get(0).toString().split("");
```

here name[i] will hold only string, but split("") method needs String Array in left side.

Is that for loop really needed?? Waht about removing the for loop and code it like

```
   if(cityName != null && !cityName.isEmpty()) {         

        name[] = cityName.get(0).toString().split("");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cityName.get(0).toString().split("");
```

That returns a `String[]` as result, but `name[i]` should be a `String` and not a `String[]`

Why do you split?

Answer (score 0):

The following line is wrong:

```
name[i] = cityName.get(0).toString().split("");
```

(as the exception message probably indicates). Indeed, you're trying to initialize `name[i]`, which is a String, with the result of the `split` method, which returns an array of Strings.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have any experience with Android, so I don't know what those methods should return, but String.split will return a String array. And name[i] is only a String. So you are trying to assign a String array to a simple String.

Answer (score 0):

the Split method returns an array of String ; so when you do this :

```
name[i] = cityName.get(0).toString().split("");
```

it will return an array of Strings which will contain all of letters of your String ,